# Is the use of a "composite-of-primes" variable to calculate first 'n' primes a valid example for dynamic programming?

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

Am trying to understand dynamic programming and the current understanding is that it consists of :

- a) identifying sub-problems
- b) storing intermediate results of the above mentioned sub-problems - to determine the final result.

So basically I've tried to consider the problem of calculating the first 'n' primes. The brute force technique requires evaluating each number against the same set of primes (lesser than given number).

My approach is to use a variable which is effectively a composite of all the unique primes that has been seen at that instant. For any given number, I calculate the gcd of the number under evaluation against this composite. If there is no common divisor between the composite and the number being tested, then the conclusion is that the number is a prime and I add it to the set and also update the composite number to include the newly identified prime.

This example demonstrates trading space for time which as per understanding is one of the principal goals for dynamic-programming. What I am not too sure is on the sub-problem requirement but since its building on previous results that is still implied.

I have not seen any such example before and while I do think this is a valid dynamic-programming approach wanted to clarify any how.

> Below is the sample code.

```
package com.example.so.dp;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

/**
 * 
 * @author Ravindra
 * @since 09August2019
 * <p> For SO question on DynamicProgramming </p>
 *
 */
public class CalculateFirstNPrimes {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 10000;
//      int count = 100000;
        CalculateFirstNPrimes calculateFirstNPrimes = new CalculateFirstNPrimes();

        Set<Long> setOfPrimes = new LinkedHashSet<Long>();
        Wrapper<BigInteger> bigIntegerWrapperCompositeOfPrimes = new Wrapper<BigInteger>(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
        calculateFirstNPrimes.handleCalculateNPrimes(setOfPrimes, bigIntegerWrapperCompositeOfPrimes, count);

        System.out.println("SetOfPrimes :"+setOfPrimes);
//      System.out.println("CompositeOfPrimes :"+bigIntegerWrapperCompositeOfPrimes.getReference());

        BigInteger bigIntegerCompositeOfPrimes = bigIntegerWrapperCompositeOfPrimes.getReference();
        byte[] data = bigIntegerCompositeOfPrimes.toByteArray();
        System.out.println("DataLen:"+data.length);
        System.out.println("CompositeOfPrimes(hex) :"+DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(data));

    }


    private void handleCalculateNPrimes(Set<Long> setOfPrimes, Wrapper<BigInteger> bigIntegerWrapperCompositeOfPrimes, int count) {

        BigInteger bigIntegerCompositeOfPrimesTemp = bigIntegerWrapperCompositeOfPrimes.getReference();
        setOfPrimes.add(Long.valueOf(2));
        for(long i=0, j=3;i<count; j=j+2) {
//          System.out.println(i+":"+j);
            BigInteger bigIntegerTemp = new BigInteger(Long.toString(j));
            if( bigIntegerCompositeOfPrimesTemp.gcd(bigIntegerTemp).compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) == 0  ) {
                setOfPrimes.add(j);
                bigIntegerCompositeOfPrimesTemp = bigIntegerCompositeOfPrimesTemp.multiply(bigIntegerTemp);
                i=setOfPrimes.size();

                if(i%1000 ==0) {
                    System.out.println("i:"+i+":"+new Date());
                }
            }
        }

        bigIntegerWrapperCompositeOfPrimes.setReference(bigIntegerCompositeOfPrimesTemp);
    }

}
```

> Also,

```
package com.example.so.dp;


/**
 * 
 * @author Ravindra
 * @since 09August2019
 * <p> For SO question on DynamicProgramming </p>
 *
 */
public class Wrapper<T> {

    private T reference;

    public Wrapper() {}

    public Wrapper(T reference) {
        this.reference=reference;
    }


    public T getReference() {
        return reference;
    }

    public void setReference(T reference) {
        this.reference = reference;
    }

}
```

References :

1. [hackerearth](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/dynamic-programming/introduction-to-dynamic-programming-1/tutorial/)
2. [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming/)

Is my understanding (that the above code constitutes a valid example for dynamic-programming) correct?

Comment: You may want to check this out, if this is what you're doing: [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026527/is-the-sieve-of-eratosthenes-an-example-of-dynamic-programming)

Comment: Hadn't thought of the sieve. They are not identical but the approach is similar.  Thanks!